# Unity AI character controller gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add gravity to my "residents" of a town builder game. Basically the residents just walk around to a random location, wait 2 seconds then do it again. I am trying to add gravity to them so they don't float.

```
     controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
     moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
     moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
     controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

These four lines are the gravity lines I tried added and very weird things happen such as the resident teleporting up if it touches anything, even the ground. What can I do? I basically just want the residents not to float above the ground and follow the slopes of the land like regular walking.

Below is the whole code if its needed to help solve my problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Resident : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector3 location;
private Quaternion rotation;
private int speed;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
private bool canRotate = true;

Vector3 moveVector;
CharacterController controller;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0);
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    speed = 5;
    SetRandomPos();
    StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());
}

void Update()
{
    int gravity = 20;
    moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    //Check if cjharacter is grounded
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the controller
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

    float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, location, step);

    if (canRotate)
    {
        transform.LookAt(location);
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-90, 90, 0);
        canRotate = false;
    }

    if (transform.position == location)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());
    }
}

void SetRandomPos()
{
    location = new Vector3(Random.Range(transform.position.x - 10f, transform.position.x + 10f), transform.position.y, Random.Range(transform.position.z - 10f, transform.position.z + 10f));
    canRotate = true;
}

IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine()
{

    //yield on a new YieldInstruction that waits for 5 seconds.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    //After we have waited 5 seconds print the time again.
    if (transform.position == location)
    {
        SetRandomPos();

    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Try [`controller.SimpleMove(yourVector);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html) it automatically applies gravity to any vector. Remove all of your gravity code.

Comment: @TEEBQNE yourVector in this case would just be transition.position?  If im correct then its not working, the character is just flying off screen for some reason.

Comment: It should be `moveDirection * Time.deltaTime`. The vector is the direction and scalar you would like it to move next. It would replace your `controller.Move` completely and remove **all** code related to gravity.

Comment: @TEEBQNE I'm sorry, you probably think I'm annoying now.  I just don't understand, I am probably doing it wrong.  Do you mind giving me the exact code I have to add?

Comment: I added a correction. The code is untested on my end, I just attempted to correct it as best I could from looking at it. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear what you intend to do, but saw a few issues with the code and tried to fix them. The snippet is untested, I just added what I believe to be the correction that should fix your issues.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

private Vector3 location;
private Coroutine changeMovement = null;

private float speed;
private Vector3 playerVelocity = Vector3.zero;

CharacterController controller;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    speed = 5;
    SetRandomPos();
}

void Update()
{
    bool groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    Vector3 move = (transform.position - location).normalized;
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * speed);

    if (move != Vector3.zero)
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
    }
    
    // check if we are close to our goal, then change the goal
    if (changeMovement == null && Vector3.Distance(transform.position,location) < 0.1f)
    {
        changeMovement = StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

void SetRandomPos()
{
    location = new Vector3(Random.Range(transform.position.x - 10f, transform.position.x + 10f), transform.position.y, Random.Range(transform.position.z - 10f, transform.position.z + 10f));
}

IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine()
{

    //yield on a new YieldInstruction that waits for 5 seconds.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    SetRandomPos();

    changeMovement = null;
}
```

Edit: I changed the code and used the [CharacterController.Move](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) as a base.

Comment: the character stands still for a little then teleports upwards?

Comment: Yes this is probably due to this line `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-90, 90, 0);`. Why do you have this in your rotation? `LookAt` should look at where you want to move to. The extra rotation is the issue. I removed them in the snippet. Try it again.

Comment: I just want to make sure, 'step' is just 'float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;' from my earlier code I presume because just copying and pasting your code 'step' is undefined.  If this is true then the character just goes flying upwards.

Comment: Yes, it should be that value. Did you remove the random rotation you are assigning the player? The `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-90, 90, 0);`.

Comment: yes, what is happening now is once the character gets spawned in, he goes flying upwards, starts to slowly fall and then goes back up a few seconds later.  He isn't even moving forward anymore

Comment: @MatthewZ I changed the code completely to follow the example code posted on the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html). If this does not work, I would strip it down and use the example code as is. If that does not work, the issue is not this code but something else causing your issues.

Comment: Yeah, its still not working, now the character goes flying forward and I'm getting a bunch of weird errors.  Thanks for your help either way.  Ill figure this out eventually.

Comment: Do these objects have rigidbodies on them? If they do, this could be why it is going crazy. I also updated the code. I had forgotten to normalize the direction so it still had scale.